# Jquery/javascript loads on initial load(if cache is cleared)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Javascript & Jquery loads fine on incognito, on hard refresh(CTR+shift+R) or on clearing the browser cache.
But it doesn't load on normal page refresh or ctrl+R.

i have written the functions separately and calling them on page load with :

```
window.onload = function() {
     adddata();
     adddata_pages();
     adddata_views7();
     adddata_pages7();
     adddata_views1();
     adddata_pages1();
};
```

Please help me, Stuck with this for long time.

Comment: how do you include jQuery?

Comment: please write how do you include the files js...maybe the order is wrong

Comment: **jquery.min.js ,
bootstrap.min.js ,
Chart.min.js ,
jquery.dataTables.js **

These files are included in head of HTML in this order

and i have included my external script before the body tag is closed

Comment: A solution to this special problem would be to force an intial load every time the page reloads. You can do that if you add a random changing number e.g. timestamp in ur html include. e.g. `<script src="myscripts.js?timestamp=[your timestamp]"></script>`. Howewer, I'd recommend  to find the root of your problem.